# Building only subset of VTK with modules

Tags: qt, cmake, vtk, qvtkwidget

For a current project I only need a subset of VTK modules. Since there is [no binary installer for Windows](http://www.vtk.org/download/) using VTK C++ (it seems installer for Python bindings are the only ones available) I need to build VTK from source. Furthermore as I’m using CI (appveyor and travis) I need to build VTK everytime I’m pushing to my repo, therefore I’d like to keep the build times to a minimum.

These are the headers I’m using in my project:

```
<QVTKWidget.h>
<vtkActor.h>
<vtkDataArray.h>
<vtkFloatArray.h>
<vtkMarchingCubes.h>
<vtkPointData.h>
<vtkPolyData.h>
<vtkPolyDataMapper.h>
<vtkPolyDataNormals.h>
<vtkRenderWindow.h>
<vtkRenderer.h>
<vtkSmartPointer.h>
<vtkStructuredPoints.h>
<vtkType.h>
<vtkUnsignedCharArray.h>
<vtkVersion.h>
```

I already tried to determine all needed modules with the script: [Utilities/Maintenance/WhatModulesVTK.py](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Utilities/Maintenance/WhatModulesVTK.py), but still get some linker errors when compiling my project. It seems that QVTKWidget doesn’t get included correctly, but I might be wrong here. WhatModulesVTK gives me:

```
All modules referenced in the files:
find_package(VTK COMPONENTS
  vtkCommonCore
  vtkCommonDataModel
  vtkFiltersCore
  vtkRenderingCore
  vtkRenderingOpenGL
)
```

which is already not quite right, as I use VTK 7.0.0 and there is no vtkRenderingOpenGL, but only vtkRenderingOpenGL2. My CMakeLists.txt for my project currenty looks like:

```
…
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core imgproc calib3d highgui)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem system REQUIRED)
find_package(VTK 7.0 COMPONENTS vtkCommonCore vtkCommonDataModel vtkFiltersCore
   vtkRenderingCore vtkRenderingOpenGL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED QUIET)
…
```

Using VTK as a dependency, I’m building it beforehand like this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Kitware/VTK
$ cd VTK && git checkout tags/v7.0.0
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake -DVTK_QT_VERSION:STRING=5
 -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:PATH=c:/Qt/5.6/msvc2015_64/bin/qmake.exe
 -DVTK_Group_Qt:BOOL=ON
 # Here should be all needed modules, e.g. -DModule_vtkXXXXX:BOOL=ON
 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON ..
$ cmake --build .
```

Is this approach correct in general? What module am I missing in order.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to minimize build times first disable the default groups:

```
-DVTK_Group_StandAlone=OFF -DVTK_Group_Rendering=OFF
```

Then switch on all the required modules.

`QVTKWidget` is part of the module `vtkGUISupportQt` so you should build just that (`-DModule_vtkGUISupportQt=ON` instead of `VTK_Group_Qt`).

For CI consider precompiling VTK on a similar machine (e.g. Ubuntu 14.04 for Travis), then upload the resulting zip of the package to a web host. Then you can download, unzip and cache the prebuilt package in the CI job. See [this Travis setup](https://github.com/ufz/ogs/blob/master/.travis.yml) for an example.

Another option would be to use the [Conan](https://www.conan.io) package manager for which I created [VTK packages](https://www.conan.io/source/VTK/7.0.0/bilke/stable) recently.